# "Not bad either" versus "not bad neither"

Tags: negation, double-negation

There are more Google matches for the first sentence, but the last one sounds better to me. Which one is correct?

Comment: I agree with Google.  "a isn't bad, and b isn't bad either" sounds fine to me but making it neither doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use no double negatives, as a general case.  While the use of "not bad, either" is a bit on the informal side, in order to maintain proper logical sense, if you wish to use "neither", you must not use "not."

Hence:

> The food was good.  The drink was also good.

Becomes:

> The food was good; the drink was not bad, either.

Or:

> Neither the food nor the drink was bad.

Comment: There is also pretty good related discussion in this site: http://www.englishforums.com/English/IsStatementNeitherRight/vpzll/post.htm

Comment: ++Brownie points for the humor in "Don't use no double negatives."