# How to say that someone will execute none of two actions

Tags: grammar, disjunction

What is the correct way to say it: "I will not do it nor do that", "I will do neither it nor do that" or some other way?

**Edit:** I think I did not expressed my doubts well. What I am looking for is whether it is possible to use "neither" or "nor" between two subordinate clauses, such as in "I will not buy groceries neither eat at a restaurant".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of "neither... nor" versus "not ... or"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10049/), though this one is admittedly a bit broader.

Comment: It should be *neither of two actions* :)

Comment: RedDwight, I clarified the question a bit. Do you think it is a possible duplicate yet? I am used to Stack Overflow, it is a bit harder to know how to ask questions about English and I don't know if I am doing something wrong...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on ELL.

Comment: @Kris it's a question dated 2011, ELL wasn't around then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, you'd say

> I will neither buy groceries nor eat at a restaurant.

In the general case, the rule-of-thumb is to phrase the sentence as "I will neither X nor Y", where X and Y are phrases containing verbs that could independently form the two sentences "I will not X" and "I will not Y". (In our sentence, X = "buy groceries", Y = "eat at a restaurant").

In case both X and Y begin with the same verb (say *buy*), you can pull out the verb so that it distributes over the neither-nor construction:

> "I will neither buy groceries nor buy shoes." —>
>     "I will buy neither groceries nor shoes."
>
> "I will neither eat in the park nor eat at a restaurant." —>
>      "I will eat neither in the park nor at a restaurant."
>
> "I will neither do this nor do that." —>
>   "I will do neither this nor that."

etc.

Comment: In fact, you can move ‘(n)either’ and ‘(n)or’ _as far to the right_ as possible; that is, what comes after these words should be _only_ the words that are different. If you have two parallel prepositional phrases and they use the same preposition, the preposition can be put outside the ‘(n)either/(n)or’ construction: “I work in both a bar and a café” = “I work both in a bar and in a café”.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: 'I will do neither'?

Comment: This only works if the options were previously presented. Is it not possible to present both options in just one setence with subordianted clauses?

Answer (score 0):

You could always simply say "I won't do either of those".